# Не получается закоммитить в репозиторий на гитхаб

Tags: github

Пытался закоммитить в свой репозиторий на гитхаб, ни git bash, ни github desktop не хотели принимать, говоря о том, что у меня нет прав это делать. Пробовал перезаходить в аккаунт, создавать новые репозитории, создавать новые аккаунты, создавать новые аккаунты и новые репозитории на них, вот такое вот мне говорит десктоп гитхаб, все разобраться не могу, в чем проблема:

Authentication failed. Some common reasons include:

- You are not logged in to your account: see File > Options.
- You may need to log out and log back in to refresh your token.
- You do not have permission to access this repository.
- The repository is archived on GitHub. Check the repository settings to confirm you are still permitted to push commits.
- If you use SSH authentication, check that your key is added to the ssh-agent and associated with your account.
- If you use SSH authentication, ensure the host key verification passes for your repository hosting service.
- If you used username / password authentication, you might need to use a Personal Access Token instead of your account password. Check the documentation of your repository hosting service.

Понятия не имею, что не так, ничего не изменял ни в настройках новых аккаунтов, ни в настройках новых репозиториев, что делать?

Comment: _"If you used username / password authentication, you might need to use a Personal Access Token instead of your account password"_ вам надо зайти в настройки репозитория, создать персональный токен и указывать его вместо пароля в ваших программах